# Allow access from domain name only with Apache

Tags: apache

I have a bunch of scripts on a server running Ubuntu 12.04 and Apache. Currently, I can access the site both ways: via the IP and the domain name, for example: `http://example.com` and `http://1.1.1.1` where example.com has an A record pointing to `1.1.1.1`. My question is, is there a way to throw 403 or similar error when the site is accessed by the server IP and not by its domain name?

All I could find about my question is a link to the [Apache HOW-TOs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html), however, there is no information on how to achieve this whatsoever. My assumption is that I have to edit the configuration file of the default vhost, but I don't know what exactly to change. Or perhaps there's a module for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this rule in your vhost configuration

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.1\.1\.1$
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: I have replaced the placeholder with the actual IP of the server and reloaded the configuration, obviously, but it didn't work. Also, the `error.log` and `access.log` files don't show anything specific. What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you put the rule in <VirtualHost > tag of example.com ? Also - make sure that mod_rewrite is loaded in httpd.conf.

Comment: It seems like I've missed one of the escaping slashes, it works fine now. Thank you!